# Count all occurrences matching categories of list

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice, spreadsheet

I use a spreadsheet for budgeting and have individual sheets containing transactions for each year and another sheet categorising strings for my outgoings.
For example:

```
A2=Food | B2=ALDI
A3=Food | B3=TESCO
A4=Utilities | B4=BRITISH GAS
```

Each of the values in the B column should partly match the string on my transactions sheet

```
A1=21/4/2020 | B1=42343 LIDL GB, LIDL, GB | C1=-21.50
```

What I'd like to do is count all the occurrences of, for example, LIDL and ALDI in a month under the category of 'Food' so I can say 'x' amount is spent of Food, Utilities, Eating Out etc.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **PivotTable** will do the trick.

First, it's a good practice to keep all "alike" data on the same spreadsheet: I suggest combining all the spreadsheets of individual years into one. This way, filtering out a specific year could be done easily (as I see you're inserting the sate of expense in the report), while summing up all food expenses of all/several years would be much tricky without combining all of the years into one table.

Second, make sure your expenses report is defined within a **table**. If it's not, simply select the whole report (can be done by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>) and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

Third, try using more strict rules. Selecting a row by a column that "partly match" another one is rather difficult, and can be done by using VBA Macros. Instead, I suggest creating another column on the report, with a formula that will extract the relevant information from the B column (in this case, extract the first string after
the first appearance of a space, and until the next appearance of a space).

So, now you should have a column (let's say, D) with an exact info as appears on column B in your categorizing table. Let's add another column, E, with the name of the category. You can use the following formula to auto-fill the correct category for each expense (Replace CatSprd with the name of the spreadsheet that contains the categorizing table):

```
=INDEX(CatSprd!A:A,MATCH($B1,CatSprd!B:B,0))
```

Finally, create a new PivotTable (use [this guide](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html) if needed) and add your fields as you desire. I would suggest dragging the categories field into Columns area, and the date field (which can be separated into day, month and year) to the Rows area.

Good luck!